# Datastore won't save new change to entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, datastore

I'm trying to solve a bug. The following functions adds a Key object to a user's attribute called tabs. For some reason, after calling `put()` on the user entity, the newly added key isn't saved. Couldn't figure out why. Maybe there is some delay that prevents the changes from appearing immediately? In that case is memcache the solution?

```
class User(GeoModel):
    tabs = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

@db.transactional
def add_tab_transaction(self, user_key, tab_key):
    user = models.User.get(user_key)
    user.tabs.append(tab_key)
    user.put()
    logging.debug('tabs this user has:')
    logging.debug(user.tabs) # prints the list with the new value
    user = models.User.get(user_key)
    logging.debug('rechecking the same thing:')
    logging.debug(user.tabs) # prints the list without the new value
```

Comment: are you seeing this happen locally or on the server? And if the server is it HRD?

Comment: on the server, and yes it is high replication

Comment: In that case, it is possible that the put() will not have completed writing to all replicas by the time you call your get(), in which case your get() will be returning the old values. You can test this, by running another get a little later. By little, I mean like a second later. If you do this, are you still being returned the old data?

Comment: When I posted this, yes. I even checked using the datastore viewer and was seeing the old data. Today I added the transactional thingy. Now I'm testing it again and it seems to work. Very strange. Maybe the transaction decoration didn't update properly or something. I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is explained in [Isolation and Consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions#Isolation_and_Consistency).

"In a transaction, all reads reflect the current, consistent state of the Datastore at the time the transaction started. This does not include previous puts and deletes inside the transaction."

Comment: This explains the logging inside the function, but it doesn't explain why I was seeing old data in the datastore viewer, a long time (minutes) after the run of this function.

Comment: Since I can't replicate the problem now I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Uri The datastore viewer uses the same APIs as everything else. Clicking on the row will cause it to do a strongly consistent read and show you the latest data, though.

Comment: @NickJohnson That's what I'm saying - the data was not being saved (it appeared unchanged in the datastore viewer GUI, a long time after the put request).

Comment: @Uri The data _is_ being saved - the datastore viewer just has the same eventual consistency issue as everything else.

Comment: I don't know the term eventual consistency, but if I understand correctly you're just saying the entity was saved but it appears as if it didn't... then when will the new entity can be viewed? I need the values updated and then used immediately.